# Determine if a value is within some % of another value

Tags: matlab, if-statement

Let's assume I have two vectors:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [0.5,3,8]
```

Is there an `if` statement that can check if `a(i)` is within 5% of `b(i)`, rather than separately check that it is larger than `b(i) + 5%` or smaller than `b(i) - 5%`.

I am looking for something like:

```
if(a(i) = abs(5% of b(i)))
   do so and so
else 
   break;
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. "if a(i) is greater or lower in the same time than b(i) in  5%" is it "if a(i) is greater/smaller than the 5% of b(i) ?". 5% of a value is always the same. The value +- 5% is different  (b+- 5%).

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer. I hope I captured the intent of your question, please [edit] it again if I messed it up!

Answer (score 1):

To determine if the values in `a` are within 5% of the values in `b`, you can simply compute the relative difference:

```
d = (a-b)./b;
```

and determine if that difference is smaller in magnitude than 0.05 (== 5%):

```
index = abs(d) < 0.05;
```

The elements of `index` are true where the difference between `a` and `b` is less than 5% of the value of `b`. That is, `index(i)` is true if `a(i)` is within 5% of `b(i)`.